# Dynamically customize django form widgets

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Specifically I want to add an `error` class if the field is invalid. So it would render out like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="error" />
```

The example blow seems hacky and I have not seen any other examples of how to achieve this.

http://jj.isgeek.net/2010/10/27/add-error-class-to-widgets-with-errors-in-django-forms/

Is it possible to globally override the default widget templates? I would like to have classes like required (or html5 required attr) if the field is required so it can be validated with JavaScript first. With the new html5 input types coming along I'd like to be able to use `type="number"` for integer fields for instance.

I have read these docs which were not much help. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances

**Edit**
Apparently there is a `required_css_class` and `error_css_class` for forms. However, I am using modelForms and this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way beyond the hack you have already identified using the standard django.

> Is it possible to globally override the default widget templates?

How to solve this is being debated by the django developers.

For now, the solution that should appeal to you the most should be using an external package by a django core developer Carl: [django-form-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils), that allows you to override templates, include arbitrary classes and include fieldsets.

And, include the following in your `forms.py`

```
from form_utils.forms import BetterModelForm as ModelForm
```

Comment: form_utils looks like a nice replacement, thanks for the tip.